# Multiples of triangular numbers

Tags: real-numbers

I know that  $\;2T_2=T_3\;$  is a triangular number.
Can anyone suggest me other triangular numbers whose two multiple is again a triangular number?

Comment: Hint: Triangular numbers in general are of the form
$$
T_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
So if you have $2T_r = T_s$ for some pair $(r,s)$, what are their possible values?

Comment: See this near duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075913/multiple-of-a-triangular-number-is-another-triangular-number/2075965#2075965. You get a Pell equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `real-numbers`?

Comment: Another pair is $(14,20)$. And $(84,119)$, $(494,696)$  ...

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A029549